# How to use List obtained in External Event in another Class

Tags: c#, class, object, events, external

In C# language, is it possible to use a List from an External Event in another Class?

```
namespace Namespace
{  
public partial class win: Window
{
    public ExternalEvent ExEvent;
    public IList<string> materialList_W { get; set; }

    public ThirdWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }



    private void LoadMaterials2DataGrid(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //call the function to store the material list without SP
        ExEvent.Raise();

        IList<string> materialList = materialList_W;

        dataGridExcel.ItemsSource = materialList;

    }

    public class EventRegisterHandler : IExternalEventHandler
    {

        public bool EventRegistered { get; set; }
        public IList<string> materialList_W { get; set; }

        public void Execute(UIApplication app)
        {
            UIDocument uiDoc = app.ActiveUIDocument;
            Document doc = app.ActiveUIDocument.Document;

            Revit_Funtion revitFunction = new Revit_Funtion();
            List<Material> totalMaterials = revitFunction.StoreMaterials(doc);

            IList<string> materialList=new List<string>();
            foreach (Material m in totalMaterials )
                materialList.Add(m.Name.ToString());
            materialList_W = materialList;

        }
        public string GetName()
        {
            return "EventRegisterHandler";
        }
    }

}
```

}

So, I've obtained a List at EventRegisterHandler (IList materialList). I've stored the content in the materialList_W. Then I've tried to open in other class (win), in the LoadMaterials2DataGrid() button.

However this is not working.

My problem is not using the same object in different classes. That I know how to do. The problem is retrieving an object from an event handler (i.e. IList materialList_W) and use it in another class (i.e. IList materialList = materialList_W;)

Comment: It would be helpful to tag your question with the language you're working in (C#, from the looks of it).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing instantiated object from another class - c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680349/accessing-instantiated-object-from-another-class-c-sharp)